# 1 Petabit / second bisectional bandwidth - A perspective for an average person?

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, bandwidth, google-cloud-networking

I heard this phrase **"Petabit bisectional bandwidth"** while studying google cloud platform.
I did some research and I was trying to wrap my head around that number to get some perspective on it.

Assuming an average *1080p* movie demands **~ 8 GB** storage, and **1 Petabit = 125000 GB**, does it mean a network like the ones indicated on **GCP** petabit bisectional bandwidth can transfer
**~15,000** [125000/8 = 15,625] movies in *1080p* format each second through its network. Also,what exactly does that "**bisectional**" mean?

Appreciate any help in trying to understand the significance of that bandwidth

Comment: [Bisection bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_bandwidth) is the bandwidth available between all partitions.  Looking at your calculation another way, 15,625 people can each download a movie, assuming they're not limited by physical disk access.

Comment: "Bisection", not "Bisectional". These numbers are aggregate performance between two systems. The practical limit of data transfer within a Google Cloud zone for current VMs is around 25 Gbit/sec. Google specs 16 Gbit/sec. The further away the systems are, the slower the speed. To use your example of an 8 GB download in one second, all systems from the source to the destination would need to support that data transfer rate. Not possible with today's public Internet and only possible with expensive dedicated private networks. This is not yet possible with VM <-> VM in the same compute zone.

Comment: Given that 1 Gigabit/sec for a VM is pretty good and means the VM is probably working hard, 1 Petabit means Google theoretically could support 1 million VMs each transferring 1 Gigabit per second. In other words a Petabit/sec is an enormous about of data. The article you reference is almost six years old and that is a long time in our industry.